# run macro when open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have done a search. The most relevant suggests the macro name of "workbook_open"
But I still must manually invoke the module. Here's what I've coded. (Any other suggestions welcome as this is my first vba script -- at age 73)

```
Sub Workbook_Open()  
  Dim lastRow As Long     'last row with data  
  Dim thisDate As Double  'start timestamp  
  thisDate = Now()  
  With Sheets("Pressure Log")  
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'populate next row with date/time  
    Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1) = Format(thisDate, "dddd")  
    Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 1) = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")  
    Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 2) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")  
    Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 3).Select 'position for user data  
  End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put this in the Workbook's code behind (ThisWorkbook is the default).

Comment: Hi gpNadpa, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify what issue you are seeing? Is the macro just not executing when the file opens?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt feedback -- Eliot K. Yes the issue is that the macro is not executing when I open the workbook. Comintern: I do not follow what "code behind" means.

Comment: Sorry. Where should I look for "ThisWorkbook"? I am in the developer tab. My two options that I have used so far are "Visual Basic" which brings up the code above (As 'Module1') and "Macros" which lists 'Workbook_Open' and gives me options to run, edit et. al.

Answer (score 6):

In the Visual Basic Editor (VBE), bring up the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then double-click the `ThisWorkbook` module (or right-click it and select "View Code"):

[image: ThisWorkbook in the VBE's Project Explorer]

That will bring up the `ThisWorkbook` module's *code-behind*. `ThisWorkbook` represents the workbook that's hosting your VBA project; it's a special type of module that inherits all the members of the `Excel.Workbook` class, which can represent *any* Excel workbook.

At the top of the code pane, you will notice two dropdowns:

[image: code pane]

Select `Workbook` from the left-hand dropdown; the VBE generates an *event handler* procedure for the `Open` event, automatically:

[image: Workbook_Open() procedure created]

Notice the right-hand dropdown now says `Open` - if you click that dropdown, you'll find that it lists every *event* that a `Workbook` can handle; selecting one will automatically generate a method with the correct signature/prototype for it.

Now take your code and put it in that *event handler* procedure, save - and you're set! Next time that workbook is opened with macros enabled, that event handler will be invoked, and your macro will run.

Have fun! It's never too late to learn!

Comment: That did it. Thanks. This appears to be a fundamental literacy I should have had. Might you have a suggestion for "further reading"?

Comment: Well... you _can_ break things, but you have to work really hard for it to be irreparably broken.

Comment: Is _code-behind_ a term borrowed for another language? A loose term used across languages? Is the more common term code pane? +

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mathieu's answer, there's also one more way to run code upon opening workbook: you can create `Auto_Open` procedure in standard module. *Warning!* This feature can be removed in next versions of Office, however it's still alive!

In standard module:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    ' Your code
End Sub
```

In the same way you can use `Auto_Close` procedure instead of `BeforeClose` event handler.